# Pandas Calculate Daily & Monthly Average from Hourly Data

Tags: pandas, date, average

i have a DF (df2) that is 8784 x 13 that looks like this with a "DATE" column in yyyy-mm-dd format and a "TIME" column in hours like below and I need to calculate daily and monthly averages for the year 2016:

```
     DATE  TIME  BAFFIN BAY  GATUN II   GATUN I  KLONDIKE IIIG  \
8759 2016-01-01  0000    8.112838  3.949518  3.291540       7.629178   
8760 2016-01-01  0100    7.977169  4.028678  3.097562       7.477159   

  KLONDIKE II  LAGOA II  LAGOA I  PENASCAL II  PENASCAL I    SABINA  \
8759     7.095450       NaN      NaN     8.250527    8.911508  3.835205   
8760     7.362562       NaN      NaN     7.877099    7.858908  3.766714   

  SIERRA QUEMADA  
8759        3.405049  
8760        4.386598
```

I have tried converting the 'DATE' column to datetime to use groupby but I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried the following below but it is not grouping my data as expected for day or month averages when i test the calculation in Excel:

```
davg_df2 = df2.groupby(by=df2['DATE'].dt.date).mean() #
davg_df2m = df2.groupby(by=df2['DATE'].dt.month).mean() #
```

Thank you as I'm still learning python and to understand working with dates and different data types!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
# monthly
davg_df2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='DATE')).mean()
# daily
davg_df2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='DATE')).mean()
```

Comment: hi - thanks for this. I'm looking at the daily average and the first day average matches exactly to my excel average for the 24 hours of day 1 but the day 2 average does not match the Excel average of the next 24 hours for day 2.

Comment: ok, thanks. So "freq='D'" will take an average in succession at each number of rows where the day changes assuming the "DATE" column is in yyyy-dd-mm datetime format? Or, should my "DATE" column data be in yyyy-mm-dd datetime format?

Comment: ok, thanks. I found the problem. Some of my "DATE" data is in yyyy-dd-mm and some is in yyyy-mm-dd format. I need to know how to set it all to yyyy-mm-dd format - perhaps in the datetime call above?

Answer (score 1):

```
# first convert the DATE column to datetime data type:

df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'])

# create new columns for month and day like so:

df2['month'] = df2['DATE'].apply(lambda t:t.month)
df2['day'] = df2['DATE'].apply(lambda t:t.day)

# then you group by day and month and get the mean like so:

davg_df2m = df2.groupby('month').mean()
davg_df2 = df2.groupby('day').mean()
```

Comment: hi - this does not work - it does separate the month into a unique column but it still mixes the month with the day.